# Hibernate Search Throwing org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator not a subtype

Tags: hibernate-search

I am trying to integrate the hibernate search to my existing hibernate application

I am Using following versions as part of my application

Using: Java versions: 8 
hibernate.version:4.2.18.Final 4.0.5.RELEASE
hibernate-search-orm:4.4.6.Final

now i have am using Hibernate Search in my application to integrate it with my application

But while i use Hibernate Search Annotations for example@Indexed and try to start my server

the following error is thrown

ERROR:

Error creating bean with name 'myEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator not a subtype

Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator not a subtype

```
Stack Trace:

 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator not a subtype
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at .config.listener.PortalSpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalSpringContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:205)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:174)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1501)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1501)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1501)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1501)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1501)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:239)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.service.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildLifecycleControledServiceRegistry(Ejb3Configuration.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my observation   as i am using the jboss7 wher we have hibernate 5 version dependencies  and the pom.xml contains 4.2.18 hibernate dependencies and i am using compatible hibernate search for the  4.2.18 hibernate version  which results in conflicts of the dependencies between the jboss hibernate modules and dependencies from pom.xml caused this error..

Basically its hibernate dependencies compatibility issues

u can go throw the following link fro[enter link description here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274192)